# Testing a json response with request context on Flask

Tags: python, json, flask, flask-restful

I have this rest function:

```
class digitalNumbers(Resource):
    def get(self, first_number, second_number):
        return {'data': directSum.sumTwoNumberss(first_number,second_number)}

api.add_resource(digitalNumbers, '/sumtwonumbers/<first_number>/<second_number>')
```

This function returns a sum of two numbers queried on the browser, on an API fashion, like for example: `localhost:5000/80/80`

And the result in  raw data: `{"data": 160}`

Now, I want to test this, by using this very same sum, like this:

```
with app.test_request_context('/sumtwonumbers/<first_number>/<second_number>'):
    assert flask.request.path == '/sumtwonumbers/80/80'
    assert flask.request.args['first_number']['second_number'] == '{"data": 160}'
```

But it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "app.py", line 16, in <module>
 assert flask.request.path == '/sumtwonumbers/80/80'
 AssertionError
```

So, the `url` path is working perfectly, but on test I'm still trying to figure out why this error, I think there is something with the `url` response, maybe I should state that the response is json and not just the resulting number?

Comment: That sounds plausible.  After all, your response is not `160`, right?  It's `{"data": 160}`?

Comment: Hi, thought so, but the error is still there, there must be something with the test url I'm providing

Comment: Surely you would want to use `with app.test_request_context('/sumtwonumbers/80/80')`. Otherwise your "numbers", would be the strings `'<first_number>'` and `'<second_number>'`.

Comment: Yeah, right, that was it, lol, just a bit of confusion, Thank You